# in Oracle 9.2, how to compare LONG Type containing String text to a Column of VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, string, types

simple q.
in Oracle 9.2,  how to compare LONG Type containing String text to a Column of VARCHAR2.

**select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.long_value = t2.varchar2_value**

how can i execute such a query the easiest way?

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem with the SQL as you've written it?

Comment: It won't work. Try it. It throws an "illegal use of long" error.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't, directly.  Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2003/052503.html) for a function to convert longs to varchar2 so you can use it in a SQL statement. LONG is more trouble than it's worth, but sometimes you're stuck with it.

Answer (score -1):

hmm, without having Oracle accesible I'm guessing your problem is with casting to the correct types.

try `(''||t1.long_value) = t2.varchar2_value` to force a conversion

but it depends on how you have your indexes setup. If you want to utilize the index on t1.long_value you may be better of converting t2.varchar2_value to something

Comment: I don't know why Oracle implemented a datatype that's useless without the intrinsics to deal with it. Your try generates the intuitive error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG :-|

Comment: It's a legacy data type. But I agree with you, why haven't system tables been updated to reflect modern data types.